# Can I download the extra levels included in the Game of the Year edition of LittleBigPlanet?

Tags: little-big-planet

Is there any way to purchase and/or download the extra levels included in the Game of the Year edition of LittleBigPlanet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially. These packs are included for free in the GotY edition:

- [The Animal Pack](http://www.1up.com/news/big-planet-motorstorm-animal-dlc)
- [The Metal Gear Solid Costume/Level packs](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2008/12/19/lbp-premium-level-packs-costume-packs-metal-gear-solid-edition-on-the-ps-store-1223/)
- [The History Costume/Level Packs](http://www.mediamolecule.com/blog/article/history_in_the_making/)
- [The Monsters Kit and Costume Packs](http://www.mediamolecule.com/blog/article/run_and_hide_here_come_the_monsters/)

All of these are still available to download. However, the 18 custom usermade levels that come in the GotY edition are, as far as I know, only available with that purchase.